# Resque + Airbrake, not seeing exceptions

Tags: resque, airbrake

I'm using the Airbrake support that comes with Resque:

```
require 'resque/failure/multiple'
require 'resque/failure/airbrake'
require 'resque/failure/redis'

Resque::Failure::Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'xxxxx'
end

Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis, Resque::Failure::Airbrake]
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
```

And trying out a simple job:

```
class Fail
  @queue = :propagation

  def self.perform
    raise "Fail!"
  end
end
```

I see the error in resque-web, but it never shows up in Airbrake. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what's the environment name? if you're raising errors in development, you should try adding `config.development_environments = []` to your Airbrake configuration.

Comment: @shime - adding that fixed the issue (awesome). I hadn't realized that Airbrake defaulted to not sending exceptions in development. I think I'll actually set it to `['test']`. If you write this as an answer, I'll check it off.

Comment: I also has some other initializers (config/initializer/resque_retry.rb) that were setting the Resque::Failure.backend, so make sure you are not setting it multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is not that clear from the gem readme...

If you're raising errors in development, you should try adding `config.development_environments = []` to your Airbrake configuration.

Cheers from Airbrake support! :)